# EXTJS 7.3: How to export paginationgrid data into excel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I have a pagedToolbar Grid with all the data available in memory Store. How do we export grid with all pages?

grid.savedocumentas (in Exporter plugin) will export only current page.
I cannot query on server side because there are too many filters applied.

Answer (score 1):

The paging toolbar works loads only the current page into the store.
If you want to grab all data, you have to get them from the proxy.

You might want to do this in the `prepareData` method of the exporter.

```
const proxy = store.getProxy(),
      data  = proxy.getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did the same way but it gives filtered out data as well.(the data  which has been filtered from grid)

Comment: That was not part of your question, right. If you need them filtered, go ahead and filter them after you grab all the data. Should be simple and works with my answer.

Comment: @Dinkheller and Joe can you please share the code snippet on fiddle?

Comment: Can you setup the fiddle and I edit it?